# Powershell script to enter a word with one click

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I want to create a script which types a word if I press a single button. I have Logitech mouse so I can assign "Run something" to buttons". I would like to be able to type in the word with one of the buttons.

Here is the code I'm trying to use

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms    
timeout 1
'Potato'.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($_)}
```

I'm not sure that code is right, but when I assing that .ps1 file to a button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do the following:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$wshell.SendKeys('Potato')
```

This will then send the keys to the currently focused application and not a winforms object you have created.

Comment: Ahh! Thanks!

Now I have to figure out how to make so execution policy don't block that script. I don't really want to go full unristricted.

Comment: No worries! Take a look into [signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_signing?view=powershell-7.1) to get it working without changing execution policies. If my example works then accept it as the answer so other people can get to it easy.